# Is there any way to set up a redirect with a bypass url?

Tags: javascript, php, html, scripting

Is there any way to set up a redirect with a bypass url such as:

```
http://example.com/oldpage?bypass=1
```

That would bypass the redirect. But

```
http://example.com/oldpage
```

Would redirect to

```
http://example.com/newpage
```

**Thank you for the answers, I've managed to complete the task using your help :)**

Comment: The script can check `if (isset($_GET['bypass']))` before doing the redirect.

Comment: That certainly is possible using a `RewriteCond` if you are talking about redirection on the http server level which has _nothing_ to do with php. But it is questionable. Why would one want to do that? If you really have to, then I suggest you take a look at the documentation of the http servers rewrite engine. Which that is obviously depends on the type of http server you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could sort this with an if else at the start of the webpage:

```
<?php
if($_GET["bypass"] == 1) { /* ...do stuff... */ }
else header('Location: http://example.com/newpage');
?>
```

Comment: Well copied from the comment made earlier.

Comment: Hi @arkascha, I don't think the above is rocket science: not sure why you think it is copied from somewhere else? I was merely trying to help...

Comment: I think he's referring to my comment below the question.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the technology stack you're using, you should do a redirect with condition.

For Apache Server you can use something similar to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/old_page [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^bypass=1
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/new_page [R=301,L]
```

It is the same concept as the previous answer (which was using PHP).